# Console command to resurrect

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there a chat/console command to resurrect or accept some player's resurrection in Diablo 3?

The game has a bug where you sometimes do not get the death screen after dying - and losing NV5 due to that bug on inferno is not funny at all.

Comment: how do you actually get that? i'm a frequent flyer on the death mechanic and i've never experienced that before.

Comment: No idea, it just happened.

Comment: you should try killing the process in the Task Manager, then logging in again - you might end up where you were with a working button.  If that doesn't work, try disconnecting your network cable.

Comment: @fcrick: I can just press escape and logout. But in any case I lose the NV stacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no chat or console command to accept a resurrection that is known about.